# wpdb foreach loop with if/else statement

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I know this has been asked hundreds of times but I am skipping a step somewhere and would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what's wrong (or help me write it better).

I'm using wordpress/woocommerce. When a user buys a product, I insert the following into a table: user_id, email, product_id, timestamp.

On each product page I am trying to write some code that loops through the table to check if the user has bought the respective video; if so, it'll display the video, if not, it'll show some text.

My logic is a bit off, or I'm doing too much, but I am trying to follow [the example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) in the codex. Right now with the code below it will display the video for that page (since I've purchased it), but if I haven't it won't display the *else* text; I will have 6-9 videos so if I can make this code more efficient I would love to learn how. Thanks. Here is my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM awdwp_webinar_orders WHERE user_id=" . $user_id . "");

if ( $results ) {
    foreach( $results as $result ) {
        $loop_uid = $result->user_id;
        $loop_pid = $result->product_id;?>

        if ( is_product(991) && $loop_uid == $user_id && $loop_pid == 991 ) {
            echo '<h2>' . get_the_title($id) . '<h2>';
            $the_video = get_field('video_file'); 
            //display video code
        } //end if
    } //end foreach 
} else {
    echo "please purchase";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it this way:

```
global $product;
global $wpdb;
$id = $product->id;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM awdwp_webinar_orders WHERE product_id=" . $id . "");

if ( $results ) {
    foreach( $results as $result ) {
        $loop_uid = $result->user_id;
        $loop_pid = $result->product_id;

        if ( is_product(991) && $loop_uid == $user_id ) {
           //code
        } else {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM awdwp_webinar_orders WHERE user_id=" . $user_id . "");

if ( $results ) {
    foreach( $results as $result ) {
        $loop_uid = $result->user_id;
        $loop_pid = $result->product_id;?>

        if ( is_product(991) && $loop_uid == $user_id && $loop_pid == 991 ) {
            echo '<h2>' . get_the_title($id) . '<h2>';
            $the_video = get_field('video_file'); 
            //display video code
        }else{
            echo "please purchase";
        }//end if
    } //end foreach 
} else {
    echo "please purchase";
}
```

Comment: This will display *purchase* for each entry in the table that doesn't match that if statement. Right now I have two purchases (product ids = 1017, 991), and it will display the *purchase* and the video file.